# how to loop through lines matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

Could anyone please explain how to loop through lines(text data consisting of 1000 lines) to search for 2 numbers in each line?

I have to use the 2 values found to find pressure & i know how to do that. Its just the looping part that's tricky.

Thank you.

Comment: could you please add an example of the input and output that you want?

Comment: have to access values for volume and temperature from lines( there are 2 values of volume & temperature in each line) and calculate pressures for each line of values.

Comment: have been asked to use scanf function to scan values & input them into a formula to calculate pressure

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using columns, just extract the columns and do not loop at all. For instance you have a 1000x5 array and want columns 3 and 4:

```
wanteddata = data(:,3:4)
```

If you need to extract things from a string:

```
fid=fopen(data)
for ii = 1:length(data)
    linetmp = fgetl(fid)
    wanteddata = linetmp(xx:yy);
end
fclose(fid)
wanteddata = str2num(wanteddata);
```

where `xx:yy` denotes the character numbers to read from, so 20:30 reads the 20th to the 30th character from the line. You might want to separately extract the two values (using the line(xx:yy) twice for both ranges)) to automatically separate the two.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a loop in matlab as follows:

```
for k=1:1000
  %here you can do something
end
```

However, this is not efficient, as Matlab works best with matrices